# Не меняются данные в бд симулятором

Tags: xcode, sqlite, objective-c

Во время работы симулятора бд меняется, все работает корректно. Но после выхода из симулятора все данные остаются в первозданном виде. Как будто я их и не менял.
Так и должно быть? В девайсе все будет работать корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете CoreData то скорее всего вы не сохраняете контекст в `AppDelegate`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не использую Corel Data. Я использую SQLite3

Comment: ^_^ тогда как пользуете так и сохраняйте. ) UPDATE INSERT ченить такое юзаете?

Comment: и UPDATE и INSERT конечно использую. Я и говорю, что пока симулятор работает - данные добавляются и удаляются. Как только я его перезапускаю, все изменения исчезают.